# How to use Instagram graphql to get profile posts urls?

Tags: web-scraping, instagram, graphql

I'm trying to get the post urls of an instagram profile.

With the following I can get a json of the main page of the profile which includes the first 12 post urls, as the rest are loaded while scrolling down the profile page.

```
https://www.instagram.com/pele/?__a=1
```

Also with the following I can get a json which includes the users that follow the given profile, and get as many of them as I want by changing the value of "first=XXXX". (You need to be logged in to instagram for that)

```
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17851374694183129&id=590087950&first=100
```

How could I possibly get the list of posts of this user including the url (most important) but maybe also information as the likes or comments of that post using Instagram graphql ?

In fact what I need is the ID of the post (The part after /p/ ) so that I can make the url like that:
https://www.instagram.com/p/Bg1DhGmDAsU/

Answer (score 3):

Since a few days the ?__a=1 way to get the last posts is blocked.

To get the last 15 Post from a Instagram profile you have to get the url and extract the **_sharedData** JSON

**Javascript**

```
let url = "https://www.instagram.com/"+username;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    error: function () {
        //..
    },
    success: function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data.split("window._sharedData = ")[1].split(";</script>")[0]).entry_data.ProfilePage[0].graphql;
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

You can do this in client or server side without login.